# Docker in WSL - unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssl, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a problem with my Windows-WSL-Docker setup due to SSL certificates issues in Docker. The issue seems to be similar to https://serverfault.com/questions/1100480/wsl-docker-curl-60-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate but in that question the issue was in WSL itself, but in my case I can connect to https URLs from WSL, so there's no issues with it.

However, when I try to build a container from a Docker file or try to execute some SSL-requiring command from existing container I get errors, like:
[image]

```
* Expire in 50 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55b609930110)
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

The last one was for the command from the link `curl -vfsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg`.

I tried to use --insecure flags (did not help), tried to install ca-certificates and update certificates when building containers - nothing.

So I really don't know how to fix this.

My Docker versions if required: Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d; docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c;
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to proxies and network monitoring protection. The solution from here helped me: https://kontext.tech/article/1065/docker-with-wsl-2-ssl-proxy-and-ssl-certificate-problem.

I had to get a proxy certificate from admins and install it as a trusted certificate into the docker container during build. This way it worked.